# Mysql query (join)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables tbl_user and tbl_lastchangepassword as shown below

Table tbl_user

```
id|  name 
---------
1 | user1 
2 | user2 
3 | user3
```

Table tbl_lastchangepassword

```
id | loginid | date_password
----------------------------
1  |    1    |  2014-03-29
```

Relation of Above table (tbl_user.id = tbl_lastchangepassword.loginid)

How do I get output as

```
id | name| date_password
---------------------
1  |user1 | 2014-03-29 
2  |user2 | null
3  |user3 | null
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you put up an example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT U.id,U.name,P.date_password FROM tbl_user U 
LEFT JOIN tbl_lastchangepassword P ON U.id= P.loginid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select a.id, a.name, b.date_password from tbl_user As a
left join tbl_lastchangepassword As b on a.id = b.loginid
```

OR

```
Select a.id, a.name, 
( select b.date_password from tbl_lastchangepassword As b where b.loginid = a.Id) As date_password
 from tbl_user As a
```